# PHP foreach loop to normal statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing a website on Wordpess and I got some problems with a foreach loop.
I got the following code for printing some links on my website

Providing that i know each status and I want to print them in different order how can I destroy the foreach loop and just write one after the other. There are 3 different statuses and instead of showing them everytime from the first to the last, I want to order them in different ways depending on the page I am currently on. 
Any help? I understand how foreach loops work but I cant manage to do it

```
 <?php foreach ( $property_statuses as $property_status ) { ?>
        <li><a <?php if($current == $property_status->name) { ?>class="current trianle"<?php } ?> href="<?php echo get_term_link($property_status); ?>?property_layout=<?php echo $property_layout; ?>&amp;status=<?php echo $property_status->name; ?>&amp;sort_by=<?php echo $sort_by; ?>"><?php echo $property_status->name; ?></a></li>
             <?php }
```

Comment: ```$property_statuses``` is just an array and so you can sort it however you want

Comment: I know its array but you see how the <li> in the foreach loop have property_status as parameter in it. So if i want to just print 
<li> ... </li> and swap each property_status with its real name it should work?

Comment: <li><a <?php if($current == $property_status->name) { ?>class="current trianle"<?php } ?> href="<?php echo get_term_link($property_status); ?>?property_layout=<?php echo $property_layout; ?>&amp;status=<?php echo $property_status->name; ?>&amp;sort_by=<?php echo $sort_by; ?>"><?php echo $property_status->name; ?></a></li>



so in this line if i swap $propery_status->name with the value of the status for example "For Sale" it should work?